# How to see the full build queue in Jenkins

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, build-server

Our Jenkins instance has a job for our main application. It builds all git branches in the one job, and so can sometimes get pretty far behind. However, the Build Queue on the lefthand side only ever shows the next job, not all the others. Is there a way to see all the queued executions of a single job? Ideally it'd even show the branch as well.

I'm aware of solutions like creating a new job for each branch, but this really clutters up the already horrible interface, and I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: Please clear your question. As far as I get.. You have a single Jenkins job which builds all git branches. Do you want to see individual git branch queued up in the build queue? If that is the case, then it's not possible in Jenkins. Build queue only lists the Jobs and not the sub-sections of a job. If it is not what you need, then please make it more clear.. Thanks..!!

Comment: Sorry, yes let me clarify. The fact that I have a matrix build is mostly irrelevant. I simply want to see the full queue for a single job. That job happens to build multiple branches in git, so I'd also like to be able to see which branch each job in the queue is going to build. Does that make sense?

Comment: I am afraid this is not supported in jenkins. You cannot see queue for sub sections of a single job.. You will have to distribute each git branch as one job.. To make life easier so that you don't have to build all branches manually, you can configure to trigger other jobs automatically when one of your job is finished building.. I hope this is of some relevance to you.

Comment: I may still need to clarify. I'd like to be able to see a job queue for a single job (no sub jobs). Is that possible?

Comment: For a single job, with same parameters, Jenkins doesn't place a build in the queue if it already contained in the queue. You can use a simple trick to add an unused parameter and set some random value to this parameter every time you run the job. Now you can have multiple jobs in the queue for the same job.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Please create that as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single job, with same parameters, Jenkins doesn't place a build in the queue if it already contained in the queue. You can use a simple trick to add an unused parameter and set some random value to this parameter every time you run the job. Now you can have multiple jobs in the queue for the same job.